# MySQL results not displaying in table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, coda

I am teaching myself PHP and MySQL, and I am trying to retrieve some information from my database and put it into a table.

So far only the table column headers are showing up, and no information is showing up for each column. It is also taking ages for the PHP file to display.

Please can you point out the problem with my code.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Unable to select Database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<h2>$numcount rows in table_1.</h2>";
mysql_close();
?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th><font face="Futura">Type |</font></th>
<th><font face="Futura">Name |</font></th>
<th><font face="Futura">Street |</font></th>
<th><font face="Futura">Address1 |</font></th>
<th><font face="Futura">Address2 |</font></th>
<th><font face="Futura">Town |</font></th>
<th><font face="Futura">County |</font></th>
<th><font face="Futura">Postcode |</font></th>
<th><font face="Futura">Number |</font></th>
<th><font face="Futura">Latitude,Longitude</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < 843) {
$type = mysql_result($result,$i,"type");
$name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$street = mysql_result($result,$i,"street");
$addr1 = mysql_result($result,$im,"address1");
$addr2 = mysql_result($result,$im,"address2");
$town = mysql_result($result,$im,"town");
$county = mysql_result($result,$im,"county");
$postcode = mysql_result($result,$im,"postcode");
$number = mysql_result($result,$im,"number");
$latlong = mysql_result($result,$im,"latlong");
}
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Futura"><?php echo $type;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $name;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $street;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $addr1;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $addr2;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $town;?></font></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
?>
<?
echo "</table>"; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a starter, you are having an infinite loop as $i is not being incremented inside the loop. If you increment $i, it should fix the problem. What is $im?

The code should look like:

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < 843) {
    $type = mysql_result($result,$i,"type");
    $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
    $street = mysql_result($result,$i,"street");
    $addr1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"address1");
    $addr2 = mysql_result($result,$i,"address2");
    $town = mysql_result($result,$i,"town");
    $county = mysql_result($result,$i,"county");
    $postcode = mysql_result($result,$i,"postcode");
    $number = mysql_result($result,$i,"number");
    $latlong = mysql_result($result,$i,"latlong");

?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Futura"><?php echo $type;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $name;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $street;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $addr1;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $addr2;?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $town;?></font></td>
</tr>
<?php
    $i++;
} // this is where the loop is ending.
?>
<?
mysql_close(); // close mysql connection after reading data
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Comment: $im has just been realised as a spelling mistake, and $i is being incremented near the bottom of the code snippet I provided.

Comment: But $i is not being incremented within the while loop

Comment: Note that you are incrementing $i outside the loop. Use the code above to fix it.

Comment: Not a practical way and $number = mysql_result($result,$i,"number");
 usage gives error sometimes.

Comment: I personally use while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) as this is a clean way to get the loop incremented. The above snippet was based on the posted code.

Comment: @Ahmet Kemal "number" is a string not an integer

Comment: @XcodeDev it is not important. You could do everything using mysql_fetch_array that you do with mysql_result. Plus, it is a better usage and also better performance. @Rasika great minds think alike ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. mysql_result() works when you do mysql_close() before ?
2. Why not use mysql_fetch_row() here ?

EDIT WITH MORE INFOS for @XcodeDev :

You can use mysql_result() when you need a single result, for example :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users");
```

Then

```
$count = mysql_result($query, 0);
```

When you expect a single line of result with several data, used

```
$result = mysql_fetch_row($query); => $result[0], $result[1], $result[2] etc
```

Or

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); => $result['type'], $result['name'] etc
```

When you expect several lines of results with several data, used

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
    => $result[0], $result[1], $result[2] etc
}
```

Or

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    => $result['type'], $result['name'] etc
}
```

Comment: @XcodeDev you should get used to this usage. mysql_fetch_row or my choice is mysql_fetch_array is always better. There is no need to define or count a $i.

Comment: @Ahmet Kemal I am completely new to PHP/MySQL I was just following a tutorial. I will look into it now.